# Find what programs were uninstalled from Win Vista

Tags: windows-vista, uninstall

I've got a Vista machine, and I just uninstalled a bunch of programs that someone had installed and wasn't supposed to.  My supervisor now wants me to send a list of these programs to the people who have used the computer just for safe keeping.

Is there any way I can find the names of the programs I just uninstalled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way of doing this.

One way could be to:

1. Create a restore point now.
2. Make a note of what programs are installed.
3. Roll back to a previous restore point - one *before* you did your mass uninstall.
4. Make a note of what programs are installed.
5. Compare the two lists to see which ones are now gone.
6. Restore your newly created restore point.

You should now have a list of uninstalled programs and a machine back in the state you want it.

Answer (score 1):

Only if they've left some trace of themselves on the system. Although they shouldn't, it's not uncommon.

- Look at the \Program Files and Program Files (x86) directories
- Run regedit and look through the registry

Specifically;

```
  HKEY_Current_User\Software
  HKEY_Local_Machine\Software
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Event Viewer. Look under "Windows Logs" and "Application" for installation event sources such as MsiInstaller around the time of the uninstallations. This is cumbersome and may not include all uninstallations, but it is better than nothing.